# Identity operator can also check whether named types are the same rather only than reference equaliy

Tags: swift, types, identity

As far as I understand, identity operator is used to determine if two objects have the same reference. It means, in practice, the both side of the operator shall be an object.

However, I've tried the following code and it confused me of the identity operator's function of what I understand

```
class Dog {}

let d: Dog = Dog()

if type(of: d) === Dog.self {
    print("yep") //prints out "yep"
}

if type(of: d) == Dog.self {
    print("yep") //prints out "yep"
}
```

The left and right side of the identity operator is not an object but a type and it seems, for this point, semantic equivalence operator and object identity operator (looks like) works in the same way.

**Question**:

Is this a bug or I didn't get the whole point correctly.

Thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The left and right side of the identity operator is not an object but a type.

Actually, on Apple platforms, they *are* objects.

This is due to the fact that Swift classes are implemented as Objective-C classes under the hood, as Mike Ash goes into detail [in this great blog post](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-07-18-exploring-swift-memory-layout.html). This means that the metatype of a class is *also* an Objective-C class, and therefore conforms to `AnyObject`.

Because of this, you can compare class metatypes with the identity operator, as it's defined as:

```
public func ===(lhs: AnyObject?, rhs: AnyObject?) -> Bool
```

It'll compare whether the two objects are the same object, or specifically in this case, the same class metatype.

In contrast, under the hood, the metatype for a *value type* isn't an Objective-C object – it's just a pointer to some static metadata. If we rewrite your example to use a `struct`:

```
struct Dog {}

let d = Dog()

// Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to two 'Dog.Type' operands
if type(of: d) === Dog.self {
    print("yep")
}
```

You'll see that we can no longer use `===` to compare metatypes, as they don't conform to `AnyObject`. So really, the ability to use the identity operator to compare class metatypes is just a side-effect of them being implemented as Objective-C objects.

The *universal* way of comparing metatypes is with the equality operator `==`, as Swift provides an overload specifically for metatypes:

```
public func ==(t0: Any.Type?, t1: Any.Type?) -> Bool
```

This checks whether two metatypes are the same, however unlike `===`, it works with *both* class metatypes and value-typed metatypes. Under the hood, it's implemented [as a simple pointer comparison](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Builtin.swift#L151), so should always yield identical results as `===` with class metatypes.

I would therefore always recommend comparing metatypes with `==`, as you're not relying on the conformance to `AnyObject`. For example, on a Linux platform, [class metatypes *don't* conform to `AnyObject`](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/58f2a16eda4eb37edb42a246) and therefore cannot be compared with the identity operator (although interestingly, when `Foundation` is imported, it appears to add a `===` overload for `AnyObject.Type` operands – presumably to aid interoperability).

Answer (score 1):

Not a bug, they are the same thing.

Dog, as a class (type) is a singular, there can only be one. There can be many Instances but only one of the Class.

type(of: d) return the owner Class of d, Dog.self returns the Class itself. They are exactly the same object, the singular Class of Dog.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help :)